# By choosing a suitable dissection of $[0, 2]$ show that $\int^2_0 3x + 4 dx$ exists and determine its value.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

By choosing a suitable dissection of $[0, 2]$ show that $\int^2_0 3x + 4 dx$
exists and determine its value.
How do i choose a suitable dissection? I figured that since the function 3x +4 is continuous then i could choose a uniform dissection $D_n = (0,2/n, 4/n,..., \frac{2(n-1)}{n},2)$ Am i correct? Is there a dissection i could use that would make solving this question easier?

i then got $m_i = \frac{6(i-1)}{n} +4  , M_i = \frac{6i}{n} +4$ but im not getting the correct solution when finding the upper and lower sums. I'm not sure how to evaluate the limit of the summation for the upper and lower sums. Have a made a mistake somewhere?

i keep getting 6 as the answer but its supposed to be 14

Comment: Well, for the lower sum for example you're dealing with $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{2}{n} \left ( \frac{6(i-1)}{n}+4 \right )$. The tricky part is finding $\sum_{i=1}^n i$. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: is that $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ ? What i tried to do what put the n terms outside the summation and keep the i terms inside so: $\frac{-12}{n^2} +\frac{8}{n} + \frac{12}{n^2} \sum^n_{i=1} i $. am i wrong to do that?

Comment: They each get summed up, but those sums do get added together.

Comment: @Ian clearly my maths is super rusty. i understand now, thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

Since $x\mapsto 3x+4$ is continuous over the closed interval $[0,2]$ so $\displaystyle \mathscr{R}\int_{0}^{2}3x+4\, {\rm d}x$ there exists.

Now, using Riemann-sums we know
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)\, {\rm d}x=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}f\left(a+j\frac{b-a}{n}\right)$$

So, using that fact we have

- Partition of closed interval $[0,2]$ as $\frac{2-0}{n}=\frac{2}{n}$, then your partition work, i.e., $D_{n}=\{0,0+2/n,0+2(2/n),0+3(2/n),\ldots,0+ n(2/n)=2\}$.

Therefore,

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{2}(3x+4)\, {\rm d}x&=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{2-0}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}f\left(0+j\frac{2-0}{n}\right),\\ &=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{2}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}f\left(j\frac{2}{n}\right),\\&=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{2}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(3\left(j\frac{2}{n}\right)+4\right),\\&=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{2}{n}(7n+3),\\&=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(\frac{14n}{n}+\frac{6}{n}\right),\\&=14.
\end{align*}